# Calculation of sound speed profile for positive speed gradient

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, acoustics, fluid-statics, geometric-optics

I have started exploring geometrical acoustics/optics in the oceans. I came across a problem that I have been working on for two days. I have mostly solved it, but I am missing just the final step and a few minor hints.

> The research vessel on the large and deep ocean sends sound waves into
> the depths at various angles of incidence and measures the distance at
> which the sound reemerges (which always happens because the speed of
> sound increases rapidly with depth). How would one extract the depth
> profile of sound velocity from the measured dependence of distance $d$
> on the angle of incidence $\alpha$? Geometrical optics applies to the
> propagation of sound.

**Here's what I have done so far.**

Since we know that geometrical optics applies and that the speed of sound is only a function of depth, denoted as $c(y)$, we can express the refractive law (Snell's law) in its differential form as $$\frac{dc(y)}{c(y)} = -\tan(\phi) d\phi \; ,$$ where $\phi$ is the angle between the direction of sound propagation and the sea surface ("sound ray" and the sea surface).

[image]

We can integrate the given equation as follows: $$\int_{c(0)}^{c(y)}\frac{dc(y)}{c(y)} = -\int_{\alpha}^{\phi}\tan(\phi) d\phi\; .$$

This yields: $$\ln \left( \frac{|c(y)|}{|c(0)|} \right) = \ln \left( \frac{|\cos(\phi)|}{|\cos(\alpha)|} \right) \; .$$

Since the speed of sound, $c(y)$, is always positive ($c(y) > 0$), the absolute values in the left logarithm are unnecessary. The same applies to the right side of the equation because $\alpha$ and $\phi$ belong to the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, and the cosine function is always positive on this interval. Therefore, we obtain: $$c(y) = c(0) \frac{\cos(\phi)}{\cos(\alpha)} \; .$$

If we knew the explicit dependence of sound velocity on depth, denoted as $c(y)$, we could determine the maximum depth, $y_{max}$. We know that at the maximum depth, $\phi$ should be equal to 0, as the sound ray will form an angle of 0° with the maximum depth, $y_{max}$. The maximum depth can be determined from the equation:$$c(y_{max}) = \frac{c(0)}{cos(\alpha)} \; .$$

Since we want to determine the depth profile of sound velocity as a function of the distance $d$ from the angle $\alpha$, we want to relate our equation to the coordinate $x$. We do this through $\frac{dy}{dx} = \tan(\phi)$ and the identity $\cos(\phi) = (1 + \tan^2(\phi))^{-1/2}$. Taking these into account, we have:$$c(y) = \frac{c(0)}{\cos(\alpha)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2(\phi)}} \; ,$$ $$f(y) = \frac{dy}{dx} =\tan(\phi) = \sqrt{\left( \frac{c(0)}{c(y) \cos(\alpha)} \right)^2 - 1} \; .$$

Now, we can calculate the distance: $$dy = \frac{dy}{dx}dx \;\; \Rightarrow \;\;dy = f(y) dx \; ,$$ $$\int_0^{y} \frac{d\tilde{y}}{f(\tilde{y})} = x \; ,$$
and $d$ is obtained as: $$\boxed{ 2\int_0^{y_{max}} \frac{d\tilde{y}}{f(\tilde{y})} = d } \; .$$

**My question now is how to proceed and obtain the velocity profile as a function of depth, $c(y)$, if we know a set of angles $\alpha$ and their corresponding distances $d$?**