# Sound speed profile

Tags: optics, acoustics, computational-physics, geometric-optics, speed

The research vessel on the large and deep ocean sends sound waves into the depths at various angles of incidence and measures the distance at which the sound reemerges (which always happens because the speed of sound increases rapidly with depth). How would one extract the depth profile of sound velocity from the measured dependence of distance $d$ on the angle of incidence $\alpha$? Geometrical optics applies to the propagation of sound.

Here is scematics to easily imagine the problem: [image]

I have already tried to get analytical solution, but with no luck. My process can be seen here [Calculation of sound speed profile for positive speed gradient](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/768562/calculation-of-sound-speed-profile-for-positive-speed-gradient).

Currently I am trying to determine sound speed profile with vectors $\vec{\alpha}$ and $\vec{d}$, where $$\vec{\alpha} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1  \\ \alpha_2 \\ ... \\ \end{bmatrix}  \;\;\; \vec{d} = \begin{bmatrix} d_1  \\ d_2 \\ ... \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ we know $n$ elements of this vectors (how does number of elements effect the precision of our sound speed profile?).

My question, how would I get unknown sound speed profile if the above two vectors are given?
I would like to get some tips, directions, even some sort of derivations. Thnak you.